# how to call procedure in java (using hibernate session)?

Tags: hibernate

I need to insert records to oracle db. I am specifying table and class name. How to call the procedure below?

```
    <id name="userId" type="string">
        <column name="USER_ID" />
    </id>
    <property name="password" type="string">
        <column name="PASSWORD" length="10" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="username" type="string">
        <column name="USERNAME" not-null="false" />
    </property>

    <property name="superUser" type="string">
        <column name="USERTYPE" length="10" not-null="false" />
    </property>

    <sql-insert callable="true" check="none">
        {Call INSERT_USERS_PK (?,?,?,?)}    
    </sql-insert>

</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few [rules](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query) you have to follow to use sprocs in hibernate.

- It must return a result set. I think in your case you will return some dummy result set to make it work.
- You can not have it as a sql-insert. you need to make it `sql-query`.

`<sql-query name="callInsertSproc">
    <return alias="dummy" class="com.dummy.DummyObject"/>
    {? = call INSERT_USERS_PK (?,?,?,?)} 
</sql-query>`

And this is how you call the named query sproc.

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("callInsertSproc")
    .setParameter(1, <someValue>)....;
List result = query.list();
```

Comment: thanks i want more informmation on hibernate stored procedure insert

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query the official documentation on sprocs